# How do I interpret results of Cumulative Link Mixed Model? Ordinal dependent variable

Tags: categorical-data, random-effects-model, ordinal-data, cumulative-distribution-function, mean-cumulative-function

I have data that looking at disease ratings of plant roots on a scale from (0-5). Five being the most severe and 0 meaning no disease. I have 10 fungicide seed treatments including a control. Essentially there are 10 treatments and 5 blocks in an RCBD design. Plants were dug up in each plot in a W shaped pattern. So there are five samples within a plot.

```
bst19rr$Trt <- relevel(bst19rr$Trt, ref = 'Control')
```

`RootRot <- clmm(RR ~ Trt + (1|Block/Plot/Sample), data = bst19rr, threshold = "flexible")`

```
summary(RootRot) #Estimates
```

I get this as a summary output...

[image]

With an anova summary table such as this...

```
Anova.clmm(RootRot)
```

[image]

Does anyone know how I should interpret these results? Or interpret estimates? I know I can exponentiate the estimates...

[image]

But I am still confused on the interpretation of Cumulative link mixed regression models.

Here is a graph I made of the data.

What would be useful to report to an audience?

[image]

Comment: You don't have enough blocks to fit random intercepts for it. Also note the estimated variance components for both block and the plot:block interaction are zero, so these should probably be removed. As for interpretation did you check similar questions on here ?

Comment: @RobertLong Hello, so I did fit a model with just fixed effects... taking the form of model.fixed<- clm(RR ~ Trt data=bst19rr) and I compared the model or tested the fixed effect with the random effect model. Using anova(RootRot, null=model.fixed). I got a significant p-value for the full model P= 2.358e-05

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that you remove all the random effects - just those for `Block`, then see if the random intercept for `Plot:Sample` is estimate well

Comment: Thank you! I will try that.